# Umbraco create link to another page

Tags: redirect, umbraco

I have two views: order letter 
localhost:64351/order-letter
localhost:64351/basket

Both have document type and content in backoffice. I want do in order-letter view button, when I click it I will redirect to basket and I want have available backoffice content. I try do sourface controller and return View

```
  public class MainBasketSourfaceController : SurfaceController
  {
    public ActionResult Basket()
    {
        return View("~/Views/Basket.cshtml", new Models.UmbracoModels.BasketRenderModel(CurrentPage));
    }
   }
```

But this return error when I using

```
 @CurrentPage
```

How I can do redirect?

Comment: Hi piotrB, What is the error you're getting?

Comment: Cannot find the Umbraco route definition in the route values, the request must be made in the context of an Umbraco request

Comment: What is the URL your page is trying to go to at the moment? Because looking at your controller the route is probably along the lines of: /MainBasket/Basket